# Python re.search first accordance in the result

Tags: python, regex

I would like to get "begin print x;;;" in python by re.search from this:
fv (x,y,z) begin print x;;; print y ;;; return x + y + z end;

I tried this: `begin = re.search("begin .+;;;", line)`

But this returns the following string: "begin print x;;; print y ;;;"
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repetition is greedy by default, meaning that it will match as many characters as possible.  This results in the `.+` passing right by the first `;;;` and matching the rest of the string up until the final `;;;`.

To prevent this, change the `.+` to `.+?`, which makes the repetition lazy (match as few characters as possible):

```
begin = re.search("begin .+?;;;", line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) version of +. By default, `.+` will match as many characters as possible, and so it will catch everything from 'begin' to the last occurance of ';;;'. Try `re.search("begin .+?;;;", line)` instead.